# Using my State employee ID in Vegas

Tags: paperwork, identity-cards, las-vegas, nevada

I will not have my new driver's license in time for my trip to Las Vegas. I know they’re pretty strict with IDs. Will my California State Employee ID be accepted in bars and casinos? It has my photo, birthdate, and expiration date, signature, height, weight, etc. stating that I’m an employee in the Department of Corrections and Rehabilitation. It also has the Department of Corrections and Rehabilitation for the State of California watermarks.

Comment: Who is "they" that should accept it?  TSA at the airport? The hotel clerk when you check in? Bars? Casinos?

Comment: Will bars and Casinos accept that form of ID?

Comment: It should be fine for bars, but might not be accepted for gambling. Have you got a passport?

Comment: No passport. Not too worried about gambling though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I lived in Las Vegas for about a year. I was never once checked for Id. Come to think about it I have never been checked for ID at any casino anywhere. Maybe I just look old.

Comment: I've been checked when I won a jackpot at the poker table, but otherwise also never been asked for one.